# TypeError: Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of undefined

Tags: node.js, vue.js, bootstrap-table

Front end in vue js.I have used bootstrap table to display the data.I want to displat the data as row-grouping.So i have used group-by-v2 from bootstrap table.That time i am getting an error.as TypeError: Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of undefined

```
        <table id="runningbet-table"
               class="table"
                data-toolbar=".toolbar"
                data-search="true"
                data-show-refresh="true"
                data-show-toggle="true"
                data-show-columns="true"
                data-show-export="true"

                data-pagination="true"
                data-locale="en-US"
                data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, ALL]"
                data-show-footer="false"
                data-toggle="context"
                data-target=".context-table"
                data-row-style="rowdollarStyles"
                data-group-by="true"
                  data-group-by-field="mode"
               >
            <thead>

            <tr >
                <th data-field="_id" data-class="d-none" >id</th>
               <th data-field="mode">Mode</th>
                <th data-field="results">Results</th>
                <th data-field="subs_mappings">Subcription</th>
                <th data-field="status">Status</th>
            </tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of undefined

Comment: Does your data have a field called "mode"? Can you give a sample of your data?

Comment: {
  "accepted": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "subs_mappings": [
        "SMC1",
        "SMC2",
        "SMC3"
      ],
      "_id": "5d3c2e64c624f74ea4a7fb4d",
      "ai": 4,
      "code": 4,
      "status": "A",
      "type": 1,
      "mode": "Single",
      "todaytime": "1564225124822",
      "cou_cd": "CC5",
      "cor_cd": "COU5",
      "rac_cd": "R5",
      "bet_cd": "BT4",
      "time": "2019-07-27T16:33:00.000Z",
      "is_free": true,
      "selections": "dgdf",
      "results": "-"
    
    }
  ],
  "status": 200
}

Comment: mode is coming from node js..it is not showing in vue